# Referring to template parameters to define types for function parameter

Tags: c++

I would like to do something like this:

```
template <typename T, int Size>
struct config {
 T field;
 /* various other things */
}

template <typename C>  //  where C is a specific version of the 'config' object. 
void func(C arg0, C::T arg1, std::array<int, C::Size> &arg2) {
   int i = C::Size;
}
```

ie, can I choose the types my function parameters based on the full type of `config`?

I could achieve this by just listing out all the individual types:

```
template <typename T, int Size>
void func(config<T,Size> config, T arg1, std::array<int, Size> &arg2) { ... }
```

But my full use case is acquiring quite a large number of parameters, both compile-time and run-time, and I'd like to package them up into my config object and pass it around, without having to replicate many template definitions at dozens of function declarations.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just a side note: Correct type to specify sizes is not `int` but `size_t`...

Comment: An actusl [mcve] would help with explaining what you actually want.  All of your pseudo code fails to compile in ways that may or may not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course add a type alias/static constexpr to `config`, but the only way to guarantee the first parameter of the function is instantiation of `config`, is the second alternative.

A solution using type alias/ static const:

```
template <class T, int N>
struct config
{
    using FieldType = T;
    static constexpr int Size = N;

    FieldType field;
};

template <typename C> 
void func(C arg0, typename C::FieldType arg1, std::array<int, C::Size> &arg2) {
   int i = C::Size;
}
```

Comment: To be noted: This alternative solution would allow for *any* type providing the `FieldType` alias and a `Size` constant (-> duck-typing). Might be acceptable or not...